# Filename Extract - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I’m having trouble extracting some data from a filename as it seems to be adding a space to the end of the extracted name even if I try using the .trim() trick to remove it doesn’t work. I have also tried counting the length of the filename -1 and it leaves the space but removed the last character instead.. this is making it very difficult for me to direct a path to a folder created as it’s I putting the space into the path..

File names below which I’m trying to extract data from

```
12 Monkeys S02E10 - Fatherland.txt
Colony S02E01 - Eleven Thirteen.txt
Prison Break S05E05 - Contingency.txt
```

I’m trying to extract the tv show name and create a folder in a new directory then move the file into the folder created..

Here is the code I am using..

```
$TRANSFER = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TRANSFER\'
$TVSHOWS = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TV_SHOW\'
$pattern = ‘\s+\S[0-9][0-9].*’

Get-ChildItem "$TRANSFER/*.txt" |
    ForEach-Object{

        $target = $_.BaseName -split $pattern

        Write-Host $target@123

      $jon = $TVSHOWS+$target


        If( -not (test-path $jon)) 
            {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -force -Path $jon
            }

        Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -Destination $jon
        }
```

And here is the error

```
Quantico @123
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TV_SHOW\Quantico \Quantico S02E10 - 
JMPALM.txt'.
At line:20 char:9
+         Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -Destination $jon
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerSh 
   ell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

As you can see I have for this illustration put the variable (tv show name) into a ‘sentence’ so you can see the space added to it.. I have tried adding \s+ which removes one of the spaces but I can’t get rid of th other one regardless of using the trim trick or not..

Can someone help, thanks
Connor Bracegirdle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show a proper Regular Expression is very well capable of
getting not only the name but all elements contained in the file name
by using capture groups enclosing the parts in parentheses

**EDIT see the RegEX live on https://regex101.com/r/Vbhq7D/1 **

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\10\SU_1330038.ps1
$TRANSFER = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TRANSFER\'
$TVSHOWS  = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TV_SHOW\'

$Pattern = '(.*)\s+S(\d{2})E(\d{2})[\- ]+(.*)'
Get-ChildItem $TVSHOWS *.txt| Where-Object BaseName -match $Pattern |
    ForEach-Object{
        $jon = Join-Path $TVSHOWS $Matches[1]

        If( -not (Test-Path $jon)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $jon |Out-Null
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $jon

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name   = $Matches[1]
            Series = $Matches[2]
            Episode= $Matches[3]
            Title  = $Matches[4]
        }
    }
```

The script does the sub dir creation, the copy and also shows this output:

```
Name         Series Episode Title
----         ------ ------- -----
12 Monkeys   02     10      Fatherland
Colony       02     01      Eleven Thirteen
Prison Break 05     05      Contingency
```

Sample tree on my Ramdrive a:

```
> tree A: /F
A:\
│   12 Monkeys S02E10 - Fatherland.txt
│   Colony S02E01 - Eleven Thirteen.txt
│   Prison Break S05E05 - Contingency.txt
│
├───12 Monkeys
│       12 Monkeys S02E10 - Fatherland.txt
│
├───Colony
│       Colony S02E01 - Eleven Thirteen.txt
│
└───Prison Break
        Prison Break S05E05 - Contingency.txt
```

Comment: Thanks LotPings, I was settling for tv show with all episodes from seasons in 1 folder to make it easier for me to write a script seen as I’m new to powershell, this gives me a good insight on how I can do the folders for seasons as well.. just a question.. how does the matches{1-4} relate to the $pattern..? How does it identify each one as an individual category?

Comment: Sorry the §$%&! Android app didn't let post a comment. I have included a link to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Vbhq7D/1) where the Regular Expression is detailed in the upper right corner. Counted from left to right each pair of parentheses (capture groups) in the pattern is stored in the collection $Matches[1..4].

Comment: Thanks LotPings, the example you have gave me with the regex website has made it very clear how to use regex as well before implementing it into my scripts. I have managed to implement seasons into this code as well.. thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Check the result of -split. It creates an array of 2 members

```
10JUN2018:012955 /:> $txts = Get-ChildItem "$TRANSFER/*.txt"
10JUN2018:012955 /:> ($txts[0].basename -split $pattern).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                            
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array   
10JUN2018:012955 /:>"some random stuff" -split " stuff"
some random

10JUN2018:013239 /:>("some random stuff" -split " stuff")[0]
some random
```

The modified code with tweak:

```
$TRANSFER = "E:\Code\PS\myPS\2018\Jun\10"
$TVSHOWS = "E:\code\PS\myPS\2018\Jun\TV_SHOW\"
$pattern = ‘\s+\S[0-9][0-9].*’

Get-ChildItem "$TRANSFER/*.txt"| ForEach-Object {
    $target = ($_.BaseName -split $pattern)[0]
    Write-Host "$target@123"
    $jon = $TVSHOWS+$target
}
```

Output:

```
12 Monkeys@123
Colony@123
Prison Break@123
```

Comment: Thanks Ketanbhut! Been trying to solve this for a few days now.. I did try the [0] at the end of the split but didn’t think to try the brackets! Something so simple, thanks for explaining it as well, much apprciated